# why the @ConfigurationProperties could not read the properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to define a class to read the spring boot application.properties, this is the model class:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.common.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dolphin.redis")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class CruiseRedisKeysConfig {

    private String userSubArticleKey;

}
```

and this is the start up class:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CruiseRedisKeysConfig.class)
public class AppStarter {}
```

but when I using this configuration, the userSubArticleKey value was null. why could not read the application.properties value? what should I do to fixed this problem? and this is the application.properties:

```
dolphin.redis.user.sub.article.key=cruise:user:sub:article:
```

Comment: Try `dolphin.redis.userSubArticleKey` or `dolphin.redis.user-sub-article-key`. I'm not sure if Spring supports mapping `user.sub.article.key` to `userSubArticleKey`.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you don't need `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`, and `@Component`. `@EnableConfigurationProperties` alone is sufficient. Alternatively you could use only `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` but move it to your `AppStarter` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java property `userSubArticleKey` will be `userSubArticleKey` or `user-sub-article-key` in your properties file:

**`application.properties`**:

```
dolphin.redis.userSubArticleKey=cruise:user:sub:article:
```

`user.sub.article.key` means the property `key` in nested object reachable via `article`, via nested `sub`, via nested `user`.